# trouble using tinymce using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I am having trouble in using tinymce editor with rails 3. I want to show text in bold letters and having trouble using tags like when I write something in p tags It should go to next paragraphs. in my case this tags is not working. It remains on same lines and display p tags on site page.

Answer (score 3):

The usual suspect when it comes to rails 3 printing raw html output to the site, is that someone forgot to call [`html_safe`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) on whatever text should be printed.

So if you have a `@my_model_instance.description` that you edit with tinymce, you might want to make the view look like `@my_model_instance.description.html_safe`, or as they suggest in the comment on the documentation, `raw(@my_model_instance.description)`.

If the text is coming from user input, however, you might want to be a bit cautious, since it might be possible for users to input all sorts of nasty injection hacks this way.